# Two factor auth: when use code always getting null from GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync

Tags: c#, .net, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to implement two-factor authentication on net 5 web app.

```
var twoFactorCodeToken = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email");
```

*Code is successfully generated and delivered to email.*

When I use that generated two factor code in the handler

```
var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
```

> I'm getting user as null.

Settings on the `Startup`

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
   ...
   options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "emailconfirmation";
   options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;            
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
  .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>>("emailconfirmation");

services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt => opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(opt => opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));

public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you call any Signin method before generating token?

Comment: nope, I'm loading the user just before generating the token. But I'm using UserManager for that. var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);

Comment: Probably that's what you are missing. First you call method `PasswordSignInAsync` if user requires two factor authentication, it will set two factor cookie underneath and this cookie will be used by `GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync`

Comment: post it as an answer and I'll accept it. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `PasswordSignInAsync` first. If user requires Two Factor Authetnication special cookie will be set which will be used by `GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I completely replace this call with

```cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

on controller. I am protecting this way an admin API access with Bearer token authentication.